# Asp .Net Web Forms removing postback from asp:linkbutton with inner HTML tags

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created my first fully functional listview with custom action buttons, that worked fine when I used asp:buttons, but I need the buttons to be icons, so I tried inserting HTML tags inside, since it can't be done out of the box, I used as:linkbuttons controls to achieve the desired look.

What it does is that the buttons trigger several actions that populate controls inside update panels, and I have my own Javascript that shows a popup on click, but on the second action it currently sends a postback and page is reloaded, I googled other questions and tried everything they had, what I tried:

**Adding a return false on client click**

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClientClick="showDialog('#popup'); return false;" CommandName="Detalles" CssClass="toolbar-button" ID="EditButton">
                            Editar 
<span class="mif-pencil"></span>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

**Using an HTML button with runat server, but Command doesn't trigger**

```
<button runat="server" onclick="showDialog('#popup');" CommandName="Detalles" class="toolbar-button" ID="EditButton">
Editar 
<span class="mif-pencil"></span>
</button>
```

**And on jQuery, but doesn't do any difference**

```
$('.toolbar-button').removeAttr('href');
```

What exactly I'm missing, my code works fine with Asp:buttons, but they can't have additional HTML :(, I'm a newbie on ASP, any hints are appreciated.

**Working button that doesn't allow inside HTML**

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Detalles" CssClass="toolbar-button fg-darkCyan button-popup" ID="btn_detalles" CommandName="Detalles">
                                </asp:Button>
```

**NOTE** Buttons are inside a ListView control, and assigned for each item.

Comment: Do you have a ScriptManager from the AjaxControlToollkit on the page? Also, have you set the UpdateTrigger for that ScriptManager? I think the CommandName may be throwing you off, but my usage of this setup is a bit rusty.

Comment: @tjcertified I do have an Script Manager on the Master file, but I don't know how to use it, but when using asp:buttons it works well

Comment: Can you post the code for using the asp:Button that works? It sounds like the button code is doing something different, but I'm not sure where the disconnect is. Also, have you tried setting the "href" property of the LinkButtons to "#"?

Comment: <button.... change to <asp:Button....

Comment: @tjcertified I indeed tried that change using jQuery, same result,I have updated question